# How to remove DONE button from large screen phones - Actionmode style in ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles, actionbarsherlock, actionmode

I'm trying to remove the DONE button and reducing the width of the DONE button size from the Actionbar. I'm using ActionBarSherlock v4.4 with Android API v19 [KITKAT] and 5 inch phone.

I'm able to do above customization with small screen android phones but when I'm going with Android Phone 4.4.2 & 5 inch and more then this DONE button is appearing in wider width. I've customized some entries in the ActionBarSherlock original library but still not getting result.

By using styles values-14 folder and small size and ICS phone below code is working good:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <style name="Theme.YourTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Nessary to Change Actionmode in ICS version -->
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_title_icon</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/ic_title_icon</item>
        <!-- Nessary to Change Actionmode in ICS version -->
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/abs__cab_background_top_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/abs__cab_background_top_holo_dark</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

But when i doing customization with same above style values-19 folder, above code is not working and showing DONE button with the ICON.

Actually, I've seen many threads in StackOverflow, I'v tested most of them but they are not removing the DONE button and reducing the width of the DONE button size with Android API v19 [KITKAT] and 5 inch/more phone.